# Black Screen after Lock Screen or Ctrl + L in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: suspend, 17.04, lock-screen

After upgrading Ubuntu from 16.10 to 17.04 on my work PC, a very strange problem is causing havoc. When I turn on my PC, everything is normal. But after Locking Computer with Ctrl+L or locking from power option, my desktop screen turns totally black, and I can just see mouse pointer. I am unable to wake computer up. I can't do anything except just restarting it.

Immediate help needed.

Comment: Are you able to switch to ttys?it's still black? if not black,  try run this `unity --reset` and get back from tty to gui if your desktop back or not, if yes, ping me; to @Dovah-king, or maybe you set configuration to suspend or sleep when lock in system configuration, check the one also